# React-Native TextInput Numbers appear first

Tags: react-native

I have a bank account input and I would like for numbers on the on screen keyboard to appear first as the default input, but would also like for letters to be used if necessary?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a keyboardType available for react-native TextInput if you want the keyboard to be appear as Numbers, Text, etc. https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#keyboardtype

But if you want it as a formatted input, like phone numbers must start with 45xxxxxxx, 78xxxxxx, you can use 'Regular Expression'.

Answer (score 0):

- ios: your best shot is `keyboardType="numbers-and-punctuation"`;
- android: I think `numeric` is good enough (for me at least. Only tested on the default keyboard of my two phones).